# Prove monotonicity of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to study whether the following sequence is monotonically increasing with $n$?

$\frac{1-(1-a^{n-1})^k}{1-(1-a^n)^k}$,

considering $0<a<1$ and $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$?

I've tried with the difference of subsequent elements like:

$\frac{1-(1-a^{n-1})^k}{1-(1-a^n)^k} \leq \frac{1-(1-a^{n})^k}{1-(1-a^{n+1})^k}$

So, knowing that $1 > a^{n-1} > a^n > a^{n+1} > 0$ and that $1 > 1-(1-a^{n-1})^k > 1-(1-a^n)^k > 1-(1-a^{n+1})^k$, but nothing comes to my mind.

Can you please help me on solving this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Consider the more general case as follows. Define $f(x)$ by $$ f(x)=\frac{1-(1-a^{x-1})^{k}}{1-(1-a^x)^{k}};\;x\geq 1,\; 0<a<1,\;k\in \mathbb{N}$$ With the aid of Mathematica, $$ f'(x)=\frac{a^{x}\left((1-a^{x})^{k-1}(-1+(1-a^{x-1})^{k}+\frac{(1-a^{x-1})^{k-1}(1-(1-a^{x})^{k})}{a}\right)k\:Log(a)}{(-1+(1-a^{x})^{k})^{2}}$$ A careful examination of the terms, imposing the constraints, shows that $f'(x)\geq 0\;\forall\:x$. Therefore, the $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing.

This includes the case where $x\in \mathbb{N}$ as posed.

Comment: Is it ok to use derivatives here?

Comment: @AntonioFerrara Yes, I think so. It is easier to examine the behaviour of a continuous function. The other way is to compare the terms of the sequence at $n$ and $n+1$, which can get tricky.